# iOS: Must I call -stopLoading before releasing a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is it necessary to do:

```
[webView stopLoading];
self.webView = nil;
```

Or, can I leave out the first line? I.e. does `-[UIWebView dealloc]` call `-stopLoading` for you?

Answer (score 4):

`-stopLoading` might be neccasary because loading is done in a seperate thread where uiwebview is retained (as a callback of a web-request afaik). if you release a uiwebview (e.g. in a `-viewDidUnload` method) i'm pretty much sure that it will stop loading but when it stops loading, it will **call its delegate**.

This will **fail** if you don't set the `yourWebView.delegate = nil` because the delegate property is defined as assign-property and therefore does not retain your delegate object (most probably a uiviewcontroller). not setting the delegate to nil will result in EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (you can actually kill some apps where you can switch between subviews containing webviews very fast - they get released before they finish loading and try to call a zombie delegate). same applies to MKMapView!

Answer (score 0):

The web view will stop loading you do not need to call stopLoading. It is not stopped in dealloc though. I believe it stops when it is removed from its superview.